# How to copy data from one table to another via JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, singlestore

I have one source table and one destination table. I want to copy data from source table to destination table. The condition is while copying data from source to destination the existing data from destination table should be erased and data of source table should be copied. I have do the JPA implementation for this. I am new to JPA. can some one help me for this how i can implement this in JPA with Spring-Data-JPA.

Comment: You need to provide some code or describe, what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. How do these two tables look? Do they have the same structure? You need to at least provide the schema of the tables or your JPA entities.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you have to do it certainly via `JPA`? It can be done in a few pieces of code of a native `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement something like that with `JPA`:

First insert data from source to desired destination table

```
@query(INSERT INTO dest
SELECT * FROM src
WHERE id =1);
```

Then delete that data from source table

```
@query(Delete FROM src
WHERE id =1);
```